# Selecting text in a TextView makes NestedScrollView scroll down

Tags: android, textview, nestedscrollview

The structure of my layout is this:

NestedScrollView

--ConstraintLayout

----Other Widgets

----TextView with textIsSelectable true

The problem is that if I select some text in the TextView, the NestedScrollView scrolls down.

Comment: It will if the cursor is moving downwards due to more text

Comment: please add your xml layout here.

Comment: In my case, I can only select the visible text. How do I make TextView (with textIsSelectable) scrollable while selecting?